# How to change default working directory on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, executable

When I double click on a Unix executable file on Mac OSX, the current working directory defaults to:

```
/Users/myusername
```

However, the executable file is actually in another directory.  How can I set the working directory to be the executable's directory instead of the `/Users/myusername`?  I know that you can do this in the source code, but is there some setting on Mac that allows you to change this prior to initial execution.

Has anyone run into this problem in the past?  It seems like a pretty default issue.

Comment: You could try to change the $HOME path for this shell

Comment: @SebastianRaschka Are there any other options?  The problem is that the executable only sees `/Users/myusername` as the general environment (e.g., when I double click on it from the desktop).

Comment: Can you give an example of the Unix application? most Unix applications can take location as a parameter if they are ran in the terminal like they are supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't even rely on the working directory being the user's home directory. On other versions of the OS, it was different and it could change in the future.

The notion of a working directory doesn't make any sense except in the context of command-line invocation. It is generally a convenience for the user to pick to allow them to specify relative paths from whatever base they prefer. If a program relies on the working directory, then it's not suitable for launching from the GUI (e.g. Finder or Dock).

You can look into wrapping the program in a script that first `cd`s to a desired directory and/or wrapping it in a [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus)-generated applet or an Automator applet.