# How to set the working directory of an executable program in Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, executable, working-directory

I created a C++ project in Xcode which successfully builds and runs a program in the Xcode environment. This program is dependent on existing in its current working directory to access several files. Outside of the Xcode environment, when I double-click on the executable file, I get a message that notifies me that the terminal exits the current working directory.

The current working directory exiting twice
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ5kc.png

After the exit messages, my current working directory results in /Users/chefjeff/

Judging by this other post: [How to change default working directory on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26951351/how-to-change-default-working-directory-on-mac-os-x)

There might not be an easy solution to double-clicking an executable so that it opens in its current directory, but I still need a solution to using the GUI on Mac in some sort of way to open the file in its working directory.

EDIT:

The project folder, CultGame, must be able to exist at any location in the user's filesystem and still have its packaged files and executable files work.

Comment: @S.M. I have the scheme edited in Xcode so that the custom working directory is what it needs to be. This is why I believe that it works in Xcode.

Comment: Get the bandle path and cwd to there.

Comment: @S.M. I looked up with 'bandle path' and found some documentation regarding bundles in mac that I will take a look at. I'll add this to the question above, but I must also mention that a requirement for this project is that the folder "cultgame" should be able to exist anywhere on a user's computer. I had previously thought of a solution that returns to the root of the filesystem and then, by hardcoding, finds the desired directory through chdir(). However, this seems infeasible at the moment.

Comment: Bundles work in the way you want; they are just directories with a special structure and the name suffix ".app", and can be moved around freely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's how I solved this:

I couldn't change the default directory that double-clicking on the program to run it would start up on.

1. I can use the chdir() function to move around directories. I moved to the root directory using chdir() after the program began and started me in Users/Username. More on chdir here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chdir-in-c-language-with-examples/
2. I used _NSGetExecutablePath() to get the directory that the currently executing file is located in. More on that here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/dyld.3.html
3. From root, I used chdir() to navigate to the path of the currently executing file which I obtained with _NSGetExecutablePath().

I will update my answer in a bit with a code example. Hopefully this helps!